# FB is not defined error in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, facebook

This error recently cropped after I installed Firefox 4.

I am using asynchronous loading of FB SDK. Have placed the fb-root div just after  tag.

I call `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();` in the `$(document).ready()`. I have added the following html tag too  :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

What am I missing ?

Try it here : http://apps.facebook.com/stockadda/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` doesn't assure you that the FB SDK has been loaded. You should make sure any calls to the `FB` object are performed when the SDK has been loaded, presumably there's a callback for the asynch load.

Comment: Ok. What's the callback ? Can I just check like if(typeof(FB)) and then execute calls ?

Comment: window.fbAsyncInit = function() { FB.init({...}) } could be what you are looking for. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ .