# FB is not defined on Firefox 4

Tags: facebook, firefox, cross-browser

FB is not defined in Firefox 4 but works on lower Firefox versions, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari. I've tried async loading and the following solutions mentioned here

[FB is not defined error in Firefox 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612211/fb-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox-4)

[How to workaround 'FB is not defined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331165/fb-is-not-defined-problem)

I've also removed extensions that could trigger this such as AdBlock.

Anybody here experienced the same thing? I don't know what I could've missed... oh boy...

Also, I am experiencing many errors in Firefox 4 when I visit other websites... makes me wonder if the FB is not defined error is a Firefox bug or something...

Man!

I'd really appreciate any opinions or suggestions... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the exact same problem but one thing that worked for me was to move the FB include right to the top of the head element.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...
```